# Slider goes out of first and last element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im new to web development. 
What i want to make is a slider for buttons.
How can i prevent it going out of first and last element? Right now i can slide it to the right on click, move it and when i click again it moves back to its initial position. 
How can i make it draggable only between the first and last element and not go out of it.
Sorry if anything is unclear.
Any help is appreciated!
Here is my code below.

```js
const track = document.querySelector('.track');
        let initialPosition = null;
        let moving = false;
        let transform = 0;
        let firstPosition = window.scrollX + document.querySelector('.track').getBoundingClientRect().left // X

        const scrollStart = (e) => {
            initialPosition = e.pageX;
            moving = true;
            const transformMatrix = window.getComputedStyle(track).getPropertyValue('transform');
            if(transformMatrix !== 'none'){
                if((parseInt(transformMatrix.split(',')[4].trim())) >= firstPosition){
                    transform = firstPosition;
                } else {
                    transform = parseInt(transformMatrix.split(',')[4].trim());
                }
            }
        };

        const scrollMove = (e) => {
            if(moving) {
                const currentPosition = e.pageX;
                const diff = currentPosition - initialPosition;
                if(diff){
                    track.style.transform = `translateX(${transform + diff}px)`;
                }
            }
        };

        const scrollEnd = (e) => {
            moving = false;
            if(transform >= firstPosition){
                track.style.transform = `translateX(${firstPosition})`;
            }
        };

        if(window.PointerEvent) {
            window.addEventListener('pointerdown', scrollStart);

            window.addEventListener('pointermove', scrollMove);

            window.addEventListener('pointerup', scrollEnd);
        } else {
            window.addEventListener('mousedown', scrollStart);

            window.addEventListener('mousemove', scrollMove);

            window.addEventListener('mouseup', scrollEnd);

            window.addEventListener('touchdown', scrollStart);

            window.addEventListener('touchmove', scrollMove);

            window.addEventListener('touchup', scrollEnd);
        }
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .carousel {
            width: 100%;
            height: 140px;
            background: #203290;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .carousel .track {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            display: inline-flex;
            touch-action: none;
        }

        .carousel .track .card {
            width: 300px;
            height: 120px;
            background: #081050;
            border-radius: 15px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        .card-button {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }
        
        .card-button-text {
            font-size: 4vh;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="track">
                <div class="card">
                    <button class="card-button"><span class="card-button-text">Link1</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <button class="card-button"><span class="card-button-text">Link2</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <button class="card-button"><span class="card-button-text">Link3</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <button class="card-button"><span class="card-button-text">Link4</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <button class="card-button"><span class="card-button-text">Link5</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <button class="card-button"><span class="card-button-text">Link6</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <button class="card-button"><span class="card-button-text">Link7</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <button class="card-button"><span class="card-button-text">Link8</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <button class="card-button"><span class="card-button-text">Link9</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <button class="card-button"><span class="card-button-text">Link10</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why not use a container with horizontal overflow (scrollLeft) instead of doing all this translate stuff?

Comment: @Jeff im learning javascript and thought i would make this. Also that would be way too easy